# InvalidOperationException: The view 'viewName' was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I just started to try out using Jetbrains Rider IDE.
In Visual Studio everything works just fine but when I start my application with Rider then I always get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: The view 'index' was not found.

The first week that I was using Rider everything worked just fine. Suddenly today this behavior started happening.

Comment: Strange, I am having this exact issue also. Unable to even find a workaround.

Comment: Okay so after a bit of digging, the issue seems to lie with SDK ver 6.0.2 and greater not being able to load the RazorSourceGenerator outside of VS2022, which explains why Rider is affected but not VS. Currently searching for a workaround for Rider.

Comment: @jhmckimm thanks for the input. I'm glad to know that I'm not the only one having this issue. But it's kinda weird because my colleagues who use the same solution are able to run the same project we're working on without any issues on Rider.

Comment: I fixed this issue. I had to go into Rider's settings (`Build, Execution, and Deployment > Toolset and Build > Use MSBuild Version`) and set the MSBuild version to use the 6.0.201 SDK instead of the 6.0.200 SDK. I pointed it to the one in the `dotnet\sdk\` one.